# Crystal reports Data field shows 0 instead of blank

Tags: database, crystal-reports

I am writing a report in crystal report and in preview some of my data fields shows zero when the data is null. However I need to show it blank instead of zero when the data is null. I have installed Vb 6.
My format field doesn't show any numbers tab

Comment: use **COALESCE(FiledName, ' ')** in your query of retrieving data from sql.

Comment: good to see you here. in crystal report are you use procedure and what is your db , is sqlserver?